# Using "for yield" to replace a string from hashmap in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a string like:

```
Template string:
I want to eat food, drink beverage at restaurant myrestaurant. 

Hashmap:
food -> pizza
beverage -> miler light beer
myrestaurant -> Papa Johns
```

Now, I want to write a `for-yield loop` to replace the template string with all of the key - values in the hashmap.

What is the best Scala way to solve it?

Comment: Why a for-yield loop? a `foldLeft` call would seem to make a lot more sense.

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: Could you have a look at the API doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'd need to **replace the terms in your template** as you keep iterating on your `hashmap`,

example,

```
scala> val template = "I want to eat food, drink beverage at restaurant myrestaurant."
template: String = I want to eat food, drink beverage at restaurant myrestaurant.

scala> val hashmap = Map("food" -> "pizza", "beverage" -> "miler light beer", "myrestaurant" -> "Papa Johns")
hashmap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(food -> pizza, beverage -> miler light beer, myrestaurant -> Papa Johns)

scala> hashmap.foldLeft(template)((a: String, b: (String, String)) => a.replaceAll(b._1, b._2))
res40: String = I want to eat pizza, drink miler light beer at restaurant Papa Johns.
```

hashmap with only two keys (`food` and `beverage`)

```
scala> val hashmap = Map("food" -> "pizza", "beverage" -> "miler light beer")
hashmap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(food -> pizza, beverage -> miler light beer)

scala> hashmap.foldLeft(template)((a, b) => a.replaceAll(b._1, b._2))
res41: String = I want to eat pizza, drink miler light beer at restaurant myrestaurant.
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

`(template /: hashMap) {case (t, (k, v)) => t.replace(k,v)}`

(`/:` is the symbolic name for foldLeft)

Not sure why you would want a for-yield for this.